# Какое расширение Flask выбрать для перенаправления?

Tags: python, flask, redirect

Подскажите, какое расширение для Flask использовать для написания кода для перенаправлений (redirects), основанных на разных регионах или странах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flask-babel позволяет выбирать содержимое на основе языка пользователя, [вот пример кода](https://github.com/zed/flask-multilang-hello-world). Если что-то не ясно, я готов ответить на дополнительные вопросы.

---

> А можно ли что бы выбирать содержимое на основе ip (местоположения пользователя)?

Да, можно. Используя какой-нибудь geoip модуль, можно найти код страны (и города), что позволяет выбрать язык.

Но не нужно. Предпочтительно выбрать язык на основе HTTP Accept-Language заголовка, генерируемого браузером на основе данных из операционной системы. Обычно браузеры предоставляют простой интерфейс, чтобы пользователь мог поменять предпочитаемые языки и их относительные приоритеты. И конечно, хорошо позволять изменять язык прямо на сайте, например, указывая его в ссылке явно. Пример кода, на который я сослался выше, демонстрирует эти возможности.

То есть выбирать язык на основе ip, нужно только в крайнем случае, если другие методы не дали результата (что маловероятно).

Comment: А можно ли что бы выбирать содержимое на основе ip (местоположеня пользователя)?

Comment: @icefromtexas: добавил инфу о geoip

Comment: Спасибо большое! а можете добавить мой никнейм в скайп (такой же как тут) пожалуйста?