# Как сменить язык пользователю на сайте Django?

Tags: python, django, локализация

Делаю возможность на сайте переключаться между русской, английской и украинской версией. Обернул строки в шаблонах, которые надо перевести, в тег `{% trans %}`, строки в коде, всё перевёл и скомпилировал перевод. Также установил `locale_url`.

В settings.py прописал:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'Ru-ru'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'locale',
     # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

Переключать язык через `POST`, так как это делается в `django.conf.urls.i18n` мне не захотелось, поэтому создал такое представление:

```py
def select_lang(request, code):
    go_next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(go_next)
    if code and translation.check_for_language(code):
        if hasattr(request, 'session'):
            request.session['django_language'] = code
        else:
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, code)
        translation.activate(code)
    return response
```

Перехожу в браузере на /lang/uk, страница перезагружается, а язык остаётся прежний. Если вводить адрес /uk/about - страница переводится, но при переходе на другую язык опять возвращается.

В чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Вот мои `middleware`, может в них дело:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

P.S. язык сайта по дефолту русский, как и весь текст в коде и в шаблонах. Но у меня по умолчанию отображается английский. Через заголовки запроса
`"Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5"`

P.S.S. функцию вьюхи проверял, на выходе у `request.session['django_language']` стоит код языка, который мне надо.

Comment: связанный вопрос (для flask) [Какое расширение Flask выбрать для перенаправления?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385127/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно в метод добавить еще:

```
request.session['_language'] = code
```

В сессии django хранит 2 параметра:
django_language и **_language**